# ADF Concept - Communication between two sites

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am developing an ADF site which is not a WebCenter Portal Application. In that site I have a page. In that page I need to give user an option to choose image. The images are available in a website, I am referring it as DAM, which is developed in Site studio and running under UCM. Each images of DAM will have a button associated with them.

The idea is as following:

1. User will go to that ADF page.
2. Click a button/link.
3. Go to DAM of UCM.
4. Choose image by clicking a button.
5. Come back to ADF Page with the dDocName of that image and that DAM will close
6. That image will get available in the ADF page.

I don't have any idea how can I implement it.
Any suggestion will be very very helpful to me. If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters to an ADF page through the URL - https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/passing_parameters_to_an_adf_p